# Third party access to attachments under the “readonly” Gmail scope

Tags: gmail, gmail-api, attachment, scopes

Accidentally gave permission to a third party app to my Gmail, under the “view your emails and settings”, the “readonly” scope
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly

Would this have given the ability for the third party to directly download attachments files from my inbox ?

Answer (score 0):

### Yes, the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/scopes) specifies for `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly`:

> Read **all** resources and their metadata

A person who has those scopes can also access your attachments and e.g. create a copy of those on his drives.

**You can easily test it yourself with a simple Apps Script code.**

E.g. send an email with attachment to yourself and run the following code:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var blob = GmailApp.getInboxThreads()[0].getMessages()[0].getAttachments()[0].copyBlob();
  DriveApp.createFile(blob).setName("copied blob");
}
```

- This code will retrieve the attachment of your newest inbox message and save it on your drive.
- If you go on `Files -> Project Properties -> Scopes`, you will see that the script automatically requested the scopes

  `https://mail.google.com/`

  and

  `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive`
- **But now, set your scopes manually** by opening the [manifest](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/manifests) (`View -> Show manifest file`) and hardcode the [authorization scopes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes) e.g.:

```
{  
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"
  ],
  "timeZone": "Europe/Paris",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8"
}
```

- Run your code again
- **You will see that it can still access and save the attachment - even with the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly` scope!**

Comment: Thank you ! I see that also you’ve added the drive scope as well, is this necessary as well as the readonly scope ? Or would using solely the readonly scope without the drive scope also allow access to attachments ?

Comment: For accessing the attchements you need only the gmail readonly scope. but in the smaple I provided the user is saving the attachement on the Google drive  (just a sample) - that is what the drive scope is for.